# Why does the object built during the test disappear during the test (with RSPEC / Rails 5.2)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am testing the avaibility of BusinessArea views in the context of signed in / not signed in user.
At the beginning of the test, I create the business area object (test_ba) thanks to the factory, which returns the object.

I 'puts' the test_ba.id to see it created.

Then I request the tested view.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe BusinessArea, type: :request do
  include Warden::Test::Helpers

  describe "Business Areas pages: " do
    test_ba = FactoryBot.create(:business_area)
    puts test_ba.id
    context "when not signed in " do
      it "should propose to log in when requesting index" do
        get business_areas_path
        follow_redirect!
        expect(response.body).to include('Sign in')
      end
     it "should propose to log in when requesting show" do
        puts test_ba.id
        get business_area_path(test_ba)
        follow_redirect!
        expect(response.body).to include('Sign in')
      end
    end
    context "when signed in" do
      before do
        get "/users/sign_in"
        test_user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
        login_as test_user, scope: :user
      end
      it "should display index" do
        get business_areas_path
        expect(response).to render_template(:index)
      end
      it "should display business area" do
        puts test_ba.id
        get business_area_path(test_ba)
        expect(response).to render_template(:show)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The test seems to run correctly, but the last step fails due to missing record!?! The ouput returns:

```
>rspec spec/requests/business_areas_spec.rb
67
.67
..67
F

Failures:

  1) BusinessArea Business Areas pages:  when signed in should display business area
     Failure/Error: @business_area = BusinessArea.find(params[:id])

     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find BusinessArea with 'id'=67 
     # ./app/controllers/business_areas_controller.rb:159:in `set_business_area'
     # ./spec/requests/business_areas_spec.rb:35:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.07 seconds (files took 13.05 seconds to load)
4 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/business_areas_spec.rb:33 # BusinessArea Business Areas pages:  when signed in should display business area
```

Can you help me find what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSpec has the `let` and `let!` methods that create memoized helpers that you should use to setup your test dependency. `let` is lazy loading (the block is not evaluated until you reference it) while `let!` is not.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe BusinessArea, type: :request do
  include Warden::Test::Helpers

  describe "Business Areas pages: " do
    let!(:test_ba){  FactoryBot.create(:business_area) }

    context "when not signed in " do
      it "should propose to log in when requesting index" do
        get business_areas_path
        follow_redirect!
        expect(response.body).to include('Sign in')
      end
     it "should propose to log in when requesting show" do
        puts test_ba.id
        get business_area_path(test_ba)
        follow_redirect!
        expect(response.body).to include('Sign in')
      end
    end
    context "when signed in" do
      before do
        get "/users/sign_in"
        test_user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
        login_as test_user, scope: :user
      end
      it "should display index" do
        get business_areas_path
        expect(response).to render_template(:index)
      end
      it "should display business area" do
        puts test_ba.id
        get business_area_path(test_ba)
        expect(response).to render_template(:show)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

> But wah! Why doesn't my code work?

In RSpec (and in any good test framework) each example runs in isolation and has its own setup and teardown. This includes rolling back the database or clearing it. RSpec does not even run the tests in consecutive order by design.

The record you are defining in the outer context will not be created for each test run. After the first example when the db is is rolled back its gone.

If you want to set something up for each test use `before`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe BusinessArea, type: :request do
  include Warden::Test::Helpers

  describe "Business Areas pages: " do
    before do
      @test_ba = FactoryBot.create(:user)
    end

    context "when not signed in " do
      it "should propose to log in when requesting index" do
        get business_areas_path
        follow_redirect!
        expect(response.body).to include('Sign in')
      end
     it "should propose to log in when requesting show" do
        puts @test_ba.id
        get business_area_path(test_ba)
        follow_redirect!
        expect(response.body).to include('Sign in')
      end
    end
    context "when signed in" do
      before do
        get "/users/sign_in"
        @test_user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
        login_as test_user, scope: :user
      end
      it "should display index" do
        get business_areas_path
        expect(response).to render_template(:index)
      end
      it "should display business area" do
        puts @test_ba.id
        get business_area_path(test_ba)
        expect(response).to render_template(:show)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But `let` / `let!` are preferred for setting up simple dependencies.

Comment: tip: don't name your variables `test_*` - in your tests everything is a test whatchmacallit so it adds nothing but noise.